# methods of an object running in parallel can't see change to attribute

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I got a object with two principals functions :
1) one is "scanning", and when find something of interest, add it to as list, an attribute of the current object. 
2) second one make operation on what is found and stored in the list.
I want the first function run for a long time, like in background, and the second one dealing with what is stored. So I tried using multithreading.

But when my first function modify the list, the second can't see the modification. Minimal example below.

Here the minimal example.

```
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as npy
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, RLock

class MyStruct(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.listOfInterest = []

    def searching(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2) # unelegant way to be sure that one process doesn't block other one from running
            a = npy.random.randn(1)[0] # random way to add something to the list
            if a>=0:
                self.listOfInterest.append(a)
                print(' add ',str(a),' to list ')

    def doingStuff(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1) 
            try:
                a = self.listOfInterest[0] # pb here : list allways empty for this function
               # doing stuff on a we don't care here
            except IndexError:
                print(' list still empty, nothing to deal with ')

if __name__=='__main__':
    mystruct = MyStruct()
    p1 = Process(target=mystruct.searching)
    p2 = Process(target=mystruct.doingStuff)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are running in different _processes_. it is absolutely normal that they cannot see each other in this way. did you mean to use threads?

Comment: @hop Unless they use shared memory, of course.

Comment: @EvyatarMeged hence "in this way"

Comment: I actually commented before your edit :<>

Comment: Just discovering parallelism. Thanks a lot, using Thread instead of multiprocess do the job !

Comment: @GuilhemL. consider posting an answer and mark it as solution

Comment: doing it in an hour or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comment of "hop" in my question, answer is quite easy. Just have to use Thread instead of process.

After a look on wikipedia, in first and rough approximation, we can say that thread and process are both a list of instruction, but thread shares memories.

If we want to be more precise (at leat if we try...), here is what happen in the problematic code :

1) we run the command "python3 MyStruct.py" , the kernel launch a process, let's call it P. This process gets its memory, and stock in some part an object mystruct build by python

2) when P runs the commands p1.start() et p2.start(), it makes what we call a fork. Like a biological cell splitting in two cells, it becomes two process, let's call then P1 et P2, each one of them independant of the other. Each of them gets a copy of the object, and works on  it. So, when one them modify listOfInterest, it's on the object is own process memory, so the other one can't see it.

if we use thread instead of process, the process P runs two threads wich are part of its, and they will share memory.

here the modify code

```
import numpy as npy
import time
from threading import Thread

class MyStruct(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.listOfInterest = []

    def searching(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2) # unelegant way to be sure that one process doesn't block other one from running
            a = npy.random.randn(1)[0] # random way to add something to the list
            if a>=0:
                self.listOfInterest.append(a)
                print(' add ',str(a),' to list ')

    def doingStuff(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1) 
            try:
                a = self.listOfInterest[0] # pb here : list allways empty for this function
                # doing stuff on a we don't care here
            except IndexError:
                print(' list still empty, nothing to deal with ')

if __name__=='__main__':
    mystruct = MyStruct()
    p1 = Thread(target=mystruct.searching)
    p2 = Thread(target=mystruct.doingStuff)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```